# onkeyup jquery function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using a javascrpt to validate a textbox and display a warning if user enter a digit otherthan 0 to 9, A to F. I see below code works fine on jsfiddle as well as on php fiddle. But When I add this on wordpress site, it is not functioning

```
<div class="input-resp-hpux-vbus"><span><input  class="textbox" id="vbus-id" name="vbus-id" type="text" /></span></div>
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/freshlife/includes/js/emcsaninfo-symcli.js"></script>
```

and javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#vbus-id').keyup(function () {
        var text_value = document.getElementById("vbus-id").value;

       if (!text_value.match(/\b[0-9A-F]\b/gi)) {
            document.getElementById("vbus-id").value = "";
            //  document.getElementById("vbus-id").focus(); 
            var message = "You have entered a invalid id.Vbus id ranges         from 0 to F in hexadecimal";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = message;
        }
        else
             document.getElementById("output").innerHTML ="";
    });
});
```

Not sure why this script is not working on my wordpress, I have v jquery version 1.10.1 on my site
Fiddle setups:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NZ6aX/4/)    [PHPFIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cwn-vdf)

Comment: what error messages do you get? Is other jquery code working on that site? I remember that in some cases you had to replace `$(stuff` etc with `jQuery(stuff` in WordPress

Comment: Why are you fetching `#vbus-id` inside your callback? Use the `this` pointer. Also, make use of the jQuery function.

Comment: @ Kaarel Kont-Kontson: I have replaced `$` with `jquery` but still it has the issue..and also other jquery codes are working fine..issue with this textbox..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress converts your single quotes (') to some unicode.

thats why your code is not working in wordpress.

Use double quotes (") in your javascript code.

and change

```
 $('#vbus-id').keyup(function () {
```

to

```
 $("#vbus-id").keyup(function () {
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Are there any Errors?
Make sure that jQuery is loaded once, and your script too..
call this url in your browser to check if everyting is right:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/freshlife/includes/js/emcsaninfo-symcli.js
```

why did you switch on Plain JS in the keyup function, you could just stay with jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#vbus-id').keyup(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $output = $("#output");
        var text_value = $this.val();
        var message = "You have entered a invalid id.Vbus id ranges from 0 to F in hexadecimal";

       if (!text_value.match(/\b[0-9A-F]\b/gi)) {
            $this.val("");
            $output.html(message);
        }
        else
            $output.html("");
    });
});
```